# Multiplatform app and consumable in-app purchases

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have a multiplatform app (Android, iOS, Windows) and implemented one license for the app. I have a webserver to make the license available across all the platforms. I use consumable in-apps to implement it. License is bought, added to a webserver and consumed.
It's consumable because it should be added to a webserver only once.
Everything was fine until now. (1.5 years since initial iOS release) Now my app got rejected. According to the apple I use incorrect in-app type. (I disputed that I have multiplatform app but they keep rejecting my app) But I do not understand what for do I need to use non-consumable in-app to make it comply to their guidelines. Any ideas what I did incorrectly and how to fix it? Should I completely remake licensing in my app?

Comment: It sounds like it should be an auto renewing or non renewing subscription.  A non renewing subscription is essentially the same as a consumable IAP.

Answer (score 1):

They may be rejecting your app since users will have no way to restore their license if they reinstall the app, get a new phone, etc. Non-consumable purchases are permanently appended to the users Apple receipt file so they can be "restored" even years after they were purchased.

The other way to offer restore functionality is if you require all users to login with app specific accounts, where you can restore any purchases directly from your server.

Usually app review provides a rejection reason and violated guidelines. Anything here?

Answer (score 0):

I had a phone call with Apple and they explained what they require:

1. Licenses must be non-consumable in-apps. Consumable in-apps may be only some kind of coins in the game and etc.;
2. non-consumable in-app should work without requiring registration;
3. If I want to have cross-platform license user may register account in our system and it should add the license from non-consumable in-app and check that this is the first time in-app with such id is used;

PS:
The idea with subscription sounds easier to implement and I decided to switch our licensing to non-renewable subscriptions as @Paulw11 suggested. The only disadvantage is that subscription must be time limited. So, I will have one year subscription.